# C++ передача указателя в функцию

Tags: c++

Есть функция с сигнатурой:

```
void some_func(Object &object);
```

Как единственный параметр, она принимает ссылку. 
Создаем указатель:

```
Object *pObj = new Object();
```

Следующий шаг, логично напрашивается, что в верхнюю функцию мы должны передать ссылку, то есть:

```
some_func(&pObj);
```

Но компилятор этот вариант не принимает, а принимает такой:

```
some_func(*pObj);
```

Вопрос:
Как я понял ранее, оператор `*`, это оператор разыменования и если мы передаем `*pObj`, тогда передаем содержимое ссылки в функцию `some_func`.

- Почему вариант с указателями работает именно так?
- Почему мы не можем в метод с таким параметром передать ссылку? `(&rObj)`
- Что происходит при передаче `some_func(*pObj)`? По моим догадкам, создается копия объекта содержимого по ссылке указателя и потом передается как параметр в метод?

Comment: Почему вы решили, что `&rObj` - это ссылка?

Comment: А разве в учебниках подробно не рассказывается обо всем об этом?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, даже у Страуструпа этот момент не описан. Видимо, маэстро, считал это самоочевидным.

Comment: @Герман Борисов, я изучал  язык совершенно самостоятельно и именно по книгам Старуструпа. И поверьте, что у меня не возникали подобные вопросы. Сами догодайтесь почему...Просто нужно изучать, а не читать.

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan *Cтрауструпа. В учебниках рассказывается, и вы правы в том, что если __изучать__, то таких вопросов __скорее всего__ возникать не должно. Однако, у автора такой вопрос возник, и это совсем не плохо, задать вопрос - это всегда хорошо. Для вас ответ, может, и очевиден, для спрашивающего - нет. И уж лучше ответить, поделиться знаниями, чем отправлять читать какой-то абстрактный учебник (дали бы уж тогда конкретное название и автора). Такие комментарии не несут пользы, а только отбивают желание изучать язык и задавать вопросы на данном ресурсе.

Comment: @Влад Сивирин, а разве я упрекал кого то?  Мой комментарий содержал только вопрос, а не упрек

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan я то как раз и стараюсь изучить этот язык, но пока что путаюсь в таких вещах. думаю это норма.

Comment: @Dima Khodan, конечно все нормально, но так как я  далеко не все учебники изучал, мне стало интересно, не поясняется ли это в других учебниках?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Токен `&`

В С++ этот токен имеет много значений:

- Как бинарный оператор - оператор побитового "и".

  ```
  0b0011 & 0b0110; // 0b0010
  ```
- Как унарный оператор - оператор взятия адреса у переменной.

  ```
  Type a;
  Type * ap = & a; // указатель на переменную типа Type
  ```
- Как часть объвления типа - модификатора типа.

  ```
  Type & r; // ссылка на переменную типа Type
  ```

## Токен `*`

Этот токен имеет такой же набор значений

- Как бинарный оператор - оператор умножения.

  ```
  3 * 5; // 15
  ```
- Как унарный оператор - оператор разыменовывания (взятие значения) переменной.

  ```
  Type a;
  Type & ar = * a; // ссылка на переменную типа Type
  ```
- Как часть объвления типа - модификатора типа.

  ```
  Type * r; // указатель на переменную типа Type
  ```

## Ссылки как значения

Работа с ссылками это как работа с их значениями.
Нельзя переопределить ссылку чтобы она указывала на другой объект.
Почти весь синтаксис для ссылки и для переменной значения одинаковый.
Ссылки обяъвляются как `Type & name`. И в дальнейшем ведут себя как обычные пермененые содержащие значение.

```
struct Type {
   int a;
}

Type o;
Type & r = o;

o.a = 1; // ok
r.a = 2; // ok
```

Переменную-ссылку можно присвоить обеъкту и наоборот:

```
Type & ref = o;
Type val;

ref = val;
val = ref;
```

Передача как аргумент функции тоже явлется присваиванием так что предыдущее верно и для них:

```
void fun1(Type x) {}
fun1(o); // ok
fun1(r); // ok

void fun2(Type & y) {}
fun2(o); // ok
fun2(r); // ok
```

## Почему нельзя присвоить указатель ссылке.

Одна из наиболее важных причин для этого заключается в том, что указатель может содержать адрес не валидного объекта. Этот процесс отдан программистам:

```
void funcp(Type* p) {
    if (p == nullptr) {
        Type & r = &p; // Здесь ОС пошлет сигнал и программа аварийно завершится
    }
    else {
        Type & r = &p; // Здесь все должно быть хорошо
    }
}
```

Также указатель можно переназначить, но в случае передачи указателя в функцию это не имеет значения.
Есть еще ряд других случаев когда ссылки и указатели служат совсем разным целям, но это повод для отедльной статьи.

Comment: Еще `&` может обозначать ref-qualifier для функций-членов класса: ```struct Some
{
    void foo() &;
};```

Comment: Спасибо, очень полезный ответ, но не совсем то, что нужно было.

Answer (score 2):

Оператор `&something` - это оператор получения адреса `something`. Поэтому когда вы пишете `&pObj`, а `pObj` - указатель, вы передаете адрес **указателя**, а функция у вас принимает адрес какой-то переменной. Оператор `*` разыменовывания указателя дает вам доступ к памяти, на которую указатель указывает, можно сказать, что вы как-будто получаете какую то переменную. И затем, при передаче в вашу функцию, ее тип неявно преобразуется к ссылке.

```
bar(int& u);

int obj;
int* pointer = &obj;
bar(*pointer); // => bar(obj)
bar(obj); // то, что вы хотели
bar(pointer); // функция принимает аргумент типа int, а не int*. Ошибка.
bar(&pointer); /* передаст адрес указателя,
    это подойдет, если bar принимает указатель на указатель: bar(int** u) */
bar(&obj); /* передаст адрес obj,
    это подойдет, если bar принимает указатель: bar(int* u) */
```

Comment: Если указатель без каких-либо операторов (`Type*  type = *ref; cout << type << endl;`) и так возвращает ссылку, тогда зачем нужно указывать оператор разыменования, для того, чтобы как раз передать эту ссылку?

_____
 <<< И затем, при передаче в вашу функцию, ее тип неявно преобразуется к ссылке. <<< к чему это преобразования в ссылку по второму кругу, если сам по себе указатель и так содержит уже ссылку???

Answer (score 1):

У вас 2 варианта. Либо использовать указатель, либо ссылку.

```
#include <iostream>

void some_func(int *obj){
    *obj = 6;
}

void some_func2(int &obj){
    obj = 5;
}

int main(){
    int obj;

    some_func(&obj);
    std::cout<<obj;//6

    some_func2(obj);
    std::cout<<obj;//5

    return 0;
}
```

&obj передаст указатель на объект, а не ссылку

```
Object *object = new Object();
//Создаётся указатель на новый объект
some_func(*object);
//* + (указатель на тип Object) = тип Object
//some_func принимает как аргумент объект, на который создаётся ссылка
//именно поэтому компилятор принимает такой вариант
```

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку функция принимает ссылку на объект **Object**, вы должны передавать в эту функцию объект типа **Object**.

Если вы передаете в такую функцию указатель на объект, это считается несоответствием типа.

Если вы делаете так:

```
some_func(&pObj);
```

То, фактически, вы передаете адрес указателя на объект типа **Object**. То есть, вы передаете указатель на указатель на объект типа **Object**.

Выражение &pObj имеет тип Object **.